# Color schemes in R?

Tags: r, plot

Does `R` have color palettes?

In other words, I am looking for an array of 6 or so color names that go well together in a graph or plot; maybe there are some predefined schemes like that?

Comment: http://www.datavis.ca/sasmac/brewerpal.html the names of the pallettes can be called using =brewer.pal(X, "PALETTECODE") where x, is a number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to generate a palette is using generic functions from the basic grDevices package:

```
rainbow()
topo.colors()
terrain.colors()
heat.colors()
```

These are useful if the desired number of colors doesn't exceed 7-8. The only necessary argument is the number of colors in palette.

There is also `gray()` function which can be used to generate various schades of gray.

Or you could do something like:

```
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue", "plum"))
barplot(t(as.matrix(mydf)), beside=TRUE, col=pal(3))
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's standard R, without the need for additional packages. (See also Marek's mention of `palette`). The other answers about RColorBrewer were also extremely helpful!

Answer (score 13):

[RColorBrewer](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RColorBrewer), as mentioned by deinst, is very useful -- even though it was designed for *maps* rather than line charts.

A number of other packages offer help with palettes:

- [gplots](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gplots) has `colorpanel()`, `rich.colors()`, ...
- [hcl-colors](http://cran.r-project.org/package=hcl-colors)
- [colorRamps](http://cran.r-project.org/package=colorRamps)
- [colorspace](http://cran.r-project.org/package=colorspace)
- [caTools](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caTools)
- [caTools](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caTools)
- ...

as can be seen from a quick query on ['palette' at rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=palette&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=www.rseek.org%2F#920).

Answer (score 9):

Look at the RColorBrewer package.  The colors are not named, but I think that they are close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Visit [this page](http://colorbrewer2.org/) before using RColorBrewer. Select the number of your data classes in the top and then define the nature of your data. You may also find [this page](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Color/Chart/) useful.

Answer (score 6):

No one mention this but look at `palette` function (`?palette`) which define default pallet.

`palette()[1:6]` gives you first six default colours.